# JSON Schema Conditionals - Different Behaviour Between IDEs

Tags: json, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I have two private IDE plugins that are generating JSON schemas to validate things. They are comprised of a bunch of `definitions` that are conditionally used with `pattern` regexs. The problem occurs in that the schema has different behaviours in IntelliJ and VS Code.

The schema is similar to below, however reduced and redacted:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
"type": "array",
"additionalItems": true,
"definitions": {
    "meat": {
        "$id": "#/definitions/meat",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "cut": {
                "$id": "#/definitions/meat/cut",
                "title": "cut",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "fillet": {
                "$id": "#/definitions/meat/fillet",
                "title": "fillet"
            },
            "bones": {
                "$id": "#/definitions/meat/bones",
                "title": "bones",
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "cut",
            "fillet"
        ],
        "additionalProperties": true
    },
    "fruit": {
        "$id": "#/definitions/fruit",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "pips": {
                "$id": "#/definitions/fruit/pips",
                "title": "pips",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "stone": {
                "$id": "#/definitions/fruit/stone",
                "title": "stone"
            },
            "citrus": {
                "$id": "#/definitions/fruit/citrus",
                "title": "citrus",
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "stone",
            "pips"
        ],
        "additionalProperties": true
    }
},
"items": {
    "$id": "#/items",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "$id": "#/items/name",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Name"
        },
        "food": {
            "$id": "#/items/food",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "allOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "food": {
                        "pattern": "meat"
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "variants": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/meat"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "food": {
                        "pattern": "fruit"
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "variants": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/fruit"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "additionalProperties": true
}
```

With YAML structure:

```
- name: orange
  food: fruit
  variants:
     pips: true
```

So with `food` being `fruit` it will match, validate and suggest for that schema, and require `stone` and `pips`.

This works in VS Code. IntelliJ however, requires `stone` and `pips` correctly, however suggests keys from `meat`'s properties.

This made me question if I have the correct implementation here - should I be using `allOf`, `anyOf` or `oneOf` here? I only need to match one. I also tried adding `else: false`, however that didn't change anything, and I still get suggestions for `meat`. When originally writing it, I think I found someone saying `allOf` will evaluate correctly as the unmatched patterns won't stop the merging of subschemas.

What I'm trying to identify is, is this an issue with my schema implementation, or a bug in IntelliJ's parsing of conditions? Or perhaps a bug in VS Code's parsing that has let me get away with faulty schemas.

Comment: `I have two IDE plugins that are generating JSON schemas to validate things.` - What are the plugins? How are they generating JSON Schemas? - You haven't fully explained what you're doing or why, or what the expected behaviour is. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - Any use of JSON Schema in an IDE is down to that IDE. JSON Schema is designed for validation but sometimes used for other things. Any other use is proprietary.

Comment: Two company private plugins, pulling data from an internal API to construct them, to provide validation and suggestions. That part is a bit less relevant. I've edited the question to include a full schema of the same structure, and the structure it validates against. I'm trying to work out if this is IDE-related or if I've got the wrong key in my schema for the conditionals really.

Comment: OK. You may not think it was relevant, but it helped. My guess here would be VSCode takes the instance (the JSON) into account, while I would guess IntelliJ does not, and simply provides all possible values for the given location. You would need to do further investigation to confirm (for example, setting `if` to `false`). They do not provide any documentation as to HOW the schemas are used, but they are mostly simple.